# Acts as paranoid gem interferes with acts as list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-list, acts-as-paranoid

I use both [acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/ActsAsParanoid/acts_as_paranoid) and [acts_as_list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) for the same model, `CheckIn`.  I have the gem setup as follows:

```
class CheckIn < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_paranoid
    belongs_to :client

    acts_as_list scope: :client, column: :week, top_of_list: 0
end
```

The ordering is scoped to the `check_ins` `client`, and I use my `week` column for the order.  If I create a `check_in`, its `:week => 0`.  If I create another, its `:week => 1`.  The issue arises when I destroy that second `check_in` and then create a third, its `:week => 2`.

Now when I look at all the `check_ins` for this `client`, the week numbers jump from 0 to 2.  Is this the intended behavior or can I do something to make the weeks sequential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From this blog](https://illuminatedcomputing.com/posts/2014/12/acts_as_list-with-soft-delete), try:

```
acts_as_list scope: 'client_id = #{client_id} AND deleted_at IS NULL', column: :week, top_of_list: 0
```

Comment: I think this will work, I'm just worried about messing up the week numbering when I go back to fix this

Comment: This is the correct answer. You need to scope on the fact that a deleted item is no longer in the list. Once you've implemented this, you could run a migration or script that loops the items and sets their week (position). Use an AR method that doesn't trigger callbacks for minimum frustration when doing this.

Comment: hmmm I'm getting an error `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'client_id'`

Comment: As in the article, you need to use single quotes, not double.  Please update your answer